# puts function gives garbage value in C

Tags: c

I want to copy one string to another string using pointer and I am getting garbage value (some unknown character) from printf function. What is wrong with it?
output is "string for copy**". At the place of ** getting some unknown character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
   char *s="string for copy",*c,*temp;//temp is used to back the 
                                      //pointer on 1st position
   clrscr();
   while(*s!=NULL)
   {
     *c=*s
      c++;
      s++;
   }
      c='\0';
      c=temp;//back pointer to first position
      printf("String from c:);
      puts(c);
      getch();

}
```

Comment: `main` always has a return type of `int`! `*s!=NULL` is a bad comparison: NULL-pointer constant to `char`. Just leave the comparison completely out, it's superfluous. Proper indentation is important for fast reading.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question, especially the part about an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37549594/16217248

Answer (score 0):

`c` is `char *` are not allocating memory to it. So referring to it - reading from it or writing to it - is undefined behavior.

Allocate appropriate memory for `c` by using `malloc()` or other function before you copy characters into it.

So problem is not actually when you try to print using `puts()` but also when you copy characters to it by `*c = *s`.

---

Other than `malloc()`, change you code as below

```
...
//allocate memory for c
temp = c;
while(*s!='\0')
{
   *c=*s
    c++;
    s++;
 }
 *c='\0'; //use *c 
  c=temp;
 ...
```

Comment: output is  "string for copy**" at the place of ** it give two unknown character.
i got your solution but how can i resolve it in the same program.
Thanks

Comment: @user3454231 Are you saying you added the malloc calls and now you're getting somewhat valid output?

Comment: Andrew_cs, I am telling about output of same program.if output is correct at all but last two character added at the end in the same program.So if char *c is not allocate the memory then how string "string for copy" is printed?

Comment: @user3454231, As I said in answer, without allocation, your program has undefined behavior. By undefined means anything can happen, you may get proper output or it may crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for your `char *` variables.

Also you never assign a value to `temp` (or allocate space for it) but then later in your code you assign `c = temp`.  This means wherever `c` is currently at in memory will get assigned whatever was in memory at the location of `temp`.