# Crash or 'segmentation fault' when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

This question is meant to be used as reference for all frequently asked questions of the nature:

Why do I get unexpected behavior, usually a mysterious crash or 'segmentation fault,' when I assign/copy/scan data to the address where an uninitialized pointer points to?

Examples:

```c
int *ptr;
*ptr = 10; // Crash here!
```

```c
char *ptr;
strcpy(ptr, "Hello, World!"); // Crash here!
```

```c
char *ptr;
scanf("%s", ptr); // Crash here!
```

Comment: The problem is more that OPs don't even know the pointer is uninitialised, but that there magically appears an object once you declare/define (they confuse this, too) pointer.

Comment: You should probably change the title if you're aiming for this question to be read by those who experience this problem **before** they post it here.

Comment: @Olaf Indeed, so then you close-vote their segmentation questions as duplicates with a link to this one. I've been missing a FAQ question like this forever; finally got around to write one down.

Comment: @barakmanos The intention is to use this post as a "canonical duplicate" for frequently asked questions. I don't really expect newbies to find it by themselves.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that after you posted that other comment above.

Comment: @Lundin: I appreciate your effort. If that is meant as a dup-CV, I'm with you. But actually I'd prefer they would find it themself before they post. But then this likely is wishful thinking anyway, as beginners tend to think their problem is unique. So, have +1 and I'll keep than in mind - thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A pointer is a special type of variable, which can only contain an address of another variable. It cannot contain any data. You cannot "copy/store data into a pointer" - that doesn't make any sense. You can only set a pointer to point at data allocated elsewhere.

This means that in order for a pointer to be meaningful, it must always point at a valid memory location. For example it could point at memory allocated on the stack:

```
{
  int data = 0;
  int* ptr = &data;
  ...
}
```

Or memory allocated dynamically on the heap:

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

It is always a bug to use a pointer before it has been initialized. It does not yet point at valid memory.

These examples could all lead to program crashes or other kinds of unexpected behavior, such as "segmentation faults":

```
/*** examples of incorrect use of pointers ***/

// 1.
int* bad;
*bad = 42;

// 2.
char* bad;
strcpy(bad, "hello");
```

Instead, you must ensure that the pointer points at (enough) allocated memory:

```
/*** examples of correct use of pointers ***/

// 1.
int var;
int* good = &var;
*good = 42;

// 2.
char* good = malloc(5 + 1); // allocates memory for 5 characters *and*  the null terminator
strcpy(good, "hello");
```

---

Note that you can also set a pointer to point at a well-defined "nowhere", by letting it point to `NULL`. This makes it a *null pointer*, which is a pointer that is guaranteed not to point at any valid memory. This is different from leaving the pointer completely uninitialized.

```
int* p1 = NULL; // pointer to nowhere
int* p2;        // uninitialized pointer, pointer to "anywhere", cannot be used yet
```

Yet, should you attempt to access the memory pointed at by a null pointer, you can get similar problems as when using an uninitialized pointer: crashes or segmentation faults. In the best case, your system notices that you are trying to access the address null and then throws a "null pointer exception".

The solution for null pointer exception bugs is the same: you must set the pointer to point at valid memory before using it.

---

*Further reading:*

**Pointers pointing at invalid data**
[How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)
[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

**Segmentation fault and causes**
[What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault)
[Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)
[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
[Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)
[What is a bus error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error)

Comment: These kind of bugs are very commonly written both by beginners who have yet not grasped what pointers are or how they work. So please note that the intention of this community wiki is therefore to keep explanations on a basic level. If you wish to leave more advanced answers with references to the C standard etc, kindly post a different answer to the question.

Comment: "It cannot contain any data." - Hmm, actually the address **is** its data.

Comment: @Olaf Keep things basic here, please :) This is intended for beginners. Though... if an address is data, then why does a CPU have both an address bus and a data bus?

Comment: Does it read the contents of a pointer variable from the address bus? ;-) (And e.g. PCIe uses a packet/command format, no classical address/data bus mechanism). There also were RAM designs that way (remember RAMBUS?) Anyway, I'm fine with the answer, should suffice for beginners. Just leave the comments if they are interested to get deeper into it.

Comment: Note on the last example: one doesn't need to dereference the pointer to exhibit undefined behavior. Like anything else, indeterminate content (the case of value for `p2`) by its very nature invokes undefined behavior when even *evaluated*, much-less furthering the madness by *dereferencing*. Yes it is a different problem, but tightly related. In summary, the statement  "It is always a bug to use a pointer before it has been initialized." is true, but "use" is not limited to only dereferencing.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I disagree partially. `int (*p)[10] = malloc(sizeof(*p));` is perfectly valid and a typical ideom.

Comment: @Olaf honestly, not sure how that relates to my comment at all

Comment: @WhozCraig: "It is **always a bug** to use a pointer before it has been initialized." is true, but "use" **is not limited to only dereferencing**."

Comment: "These examples all lead to program crashes or other kinds of unexpected behavior"  - sometimes it works "as expected", people post questions asking why their invalid pointer access *doesn't* crash when they thought it would

Answer (score 4):

1. Pointers only point to a memory location. You created a pointer but you did not bind to a memory location yet. `strcpy` wants you to pass two pointers (*first one mustn't be constant*) that point to two character arrays like this signature:

   ```
   char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
   ```

   #### sample usage:

   ```
   char* ptr = malloc(32);  
   strcpy(ptr, "hello world");
   ```

   ```
   char str[32];  
   strcpy(str, "hello world");
   ```
2. You can try the following code snippet to read string until reaching newline character (*you can also add other whitespace characters like `"%[^\t\n]s"`(*tab, newline*) or `"%[^ \t\n]s"` (*space, tab, newline*)).

   ```
   char *ptr = malloc(32);
   scanf("%31[^\n]", ptr);
   ```

   (In real life, don't forget to check the return value from `scanf()`!)

Comment: In real life, don't forget to check the return value from `malloc()`!

Answer (score 1):

One situation that frequently occurs while learning C is trying to use single quotes to denote a string literal:

```
char ptr[5];
strcpy(ptr, 'hello'); // crash here!
//            ^     ^   because of ' instead of "
```

In C, `'h'` is a single character literal, while `"h"` is a string literal containing an `'h'` and a null terminator `\0` (that is, a 2 char array). Also, in C, the type of a character literal is `int`, that is, `sizeof('h')` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`, while `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

```
char h = 'h';
printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof(h));     // Size: 1
printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof('h'));   // likely output: Size: 4
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is asking about.

Comment: 1) This has absolutely nothing to do with the question and 2) `strcpy(ptr, 'hello');` only crashes because you used a non-C compiler or didn't pay attention to warnings. A conforming C compiler is forced to issue a diagnostic message if a `char` or `int` is passed to a function expecting a  `const char*`. Parameter passing to function is done "as if by assignment" and code such as `const char* x = 'hello';` is not a valid form of assignment, hence the mandatory compiler diagnostic message.

Comment: Also, `char ptr[5]; strcpy(ptr, "hello");` is just as bad and buggy...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have **not allocated** memory for the **pointer** `char* ptr`.
In this case you have to *allocate memory* for the pointer. One way to do this is to *dynamically allocate* memory using the functions `malloc()` and `calloc()`:

```
char* ptr;
ptr = malloc(50); // Allocate space for 50 characters
strcpy(ptr, "hello world");
```

When the use of `*ptr` over don't forget to *deallocate memory* allocated for `*ptr`. This can be done using `free()` function.

```
free(ptr); // Deallocating memory
// Size of dynamically allocated memory can be changed by using realloc()

char *tmp = realloc(ptr, 100); // Allocate space for 100 characters
if (!tmp) {
    // Reallocation failed, ptr not freed
    perror("Resize failed");
    exit(1);       
}
else {
    // Reallocation succeeded, old ptr freed
    ptr = tmp;
}
```

In most cases **segmentation fault** happens due to error in *memory allocation* or *array out of bound* cases.

Answer (score 0):

For making a modifiable copy of a string, instead of using `malloc`, `strlen` and `strcpy`, the POSIX C library has a handy function called `strdup` in `<string.h>` that will return a copy of the passed-in null-terminated string with allocated storage duration. After use the pointer should be released with `free`:

```
char* ptr;
ptr = strdup("hello world");
ptr[0] = 'H';
puts(ptr);
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Please note however that `strdup` isn't standard C and not necessarily portable.

Comment: @Lundin it is conforming to *an ISO standard*, but not *the C* standard yes. As for portability, that's what the P in POSIX stands for.

Comment: Which doesn't matter the slightest when you aren't working in a PC environment.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes indeed.  The Unix programmer's definition of "portable" has generally meant "portable to another Unix".

Comment: @MikeHousky POSIX is still a real standard, one that even microsoft once cared to implement, poorly

Comment: Also, before C23 then `strdup` was crammed into string.h by the defective POSIX standard, rendering all programs non-conforming. The people who designed POSIX didn't care the slightest about portability, since by using functions in POSIX we turn our C programs non-conforming.

Comment: Specifically ISO 9899:2018 chapter 4 §6 _"A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program."_ This includes not using identifiers that are not reserved and may exist in the strictly conforming program. A strictly conforming program may have a variable `int strdup;` and POSIX would break that program. The solution is to not use or care about POSIX at all, particularly if portability is a concern. POSIX is not harmonized with ISO 9899 and never was.

Comment: For `strdup` specifically, then it will be added to ISO 9899:202x and placed in string.h. But the same defective behavior as described above still exits for a whole lot of functions in POSIX.

Comment: @Lundin you forgot, all `str`-prefixed external names have always been reserved whether or not a header has been included, and also *"Function names that begin with str, mem, or wcs and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the <string.h> header."* and if you ask kindly for the *standard-conforming compiler*, e.g. `-std=c17` from GCC you will get implicit function declaration `strdup`!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні Yeah they have always been reserved and yet POSIX has taken the liberty to ignore that. POSIX may neither use identifiers starting with `str` nor place any form of identifier inside standard library functions. It has never been compatible with C, which is why POSIX should be ignored. Why should anyone follow a standard which doesn't follow standards in itself?

Comment: POSIX is (among other things) an extension of the standard library...