# C: Allocating structs using memcpy

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I am looking at some code somewhat as below:

```
void whatDoesThisDo(uint8_t *source)
{
    STRUCT_T *pStruct;
    memcpy(&pStruct, source, sizeof(STRUCT_T));

    // this function does some stuff with struct contents
    useStruct(pStruct);
}
```

The intention of the function is to populate the struct from buffer 'source' and then call 'useStruct' (which updates a global based on the contents of the pointer to struct passed to it).

I think the code allocates memory for the pointer on the stack (so pointing to some random location), memcopy then pushes bytes from 'source' (overwriting pStruct, so that now points somewhere else), and useStruct uses content of pStruct as pointer to struct.

Comment: `memcpy(&pStruct`....hmmmm....

Comment: There are 2 errors to begin with. Starting with you haven't allocated anything at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/mysterious-crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-to-an-unini

Comment: It's not my code, I don't think it works either :-)

Comment: You need to find out what `source` points to.

Answer (score 4):

The original code:

```
STRUCT_T *pStruct;
memcpy(&pStruct, source, sizeof(STRUCT_T));
```

Copies `STRUCT_T` into `STRUCT_T*`, which is an programming error.

What you probably want is:

```
void whatDoesThisDo(uint8_t *source)
{
    STRUCT_T Struct; // Allocate a Struct on the stack.
    memcpy(&Struct, source, sizeof(STRUCT_T));

    // this function does some stuff with struct contents
    useStruct(&Struct);
}
```

That assumes that `source` points to a `STRUCT_T`.

If `source` is correctly aligned for `STRUCT_T`, then this function could be just:

```
void whatDoesThisDo(uint8_t *source)
{
    useStruct((STRUCT_T*)source);
}
```

Comment: As above..It's not my code, I don't think it works either :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will not currently work.

If you want `pStruct` to have *dynamic storage duration*, then you need to allocate memory for the destination buffer `pStruct` yourself. Use `malloc` for that. Then use `memcpy(pStruct, source, sizeof(STRUCT_T));` to copy the structure. Note that I pass `pStruct`, not an *address* to `memcpy`.

Alternatively, you could define `pStruct` to have *automatic* storage duration; i.e. write

`STRUCT_T pStruct;`

(perhaps renaming the variable so it doesn't look like a pointer type), and use `memcpy(&pStruct, source, sizeof(STRUCT_T));`

Comment: Why use malloc instead of allocating the struct on the stack?

Comment: Don't say "stack" - that's not a language concept. I've now added that possibility.

Comment: No, either are valid in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: oops. Humble pie. Grammar states sizeof unary-expression or sizeof ( type-name ). You are correct. Yet another difference between C and C++.

Comment: As above..It's not my code, I don't think it works either :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The intention of the function is to populate the struct from buffer 'source'

You haven't created any struct to populate.

> and then call 'useStruct' (which updates a global based on the contents of the pointer to struct passed to it).

That part is OK.

> I think the code allocates memory for the pointer on the stack (so pointing to some random location),

Yes. **memory for the pointer** is the key here. Not memory for the struct.

> memcopy then pushes bytes from 'source' (overwriting pStruct, so that now points somewhere else),

Yes. But you overwrote the pointer with the struct itself. The pointer doesn't make any sense now. Plus, the pointer is typically much smaller than a struct, so you overwrote not just the pointer, but also some memory after it. Which is very bad thing, because nobody can tell who used that memory and for what, so there possibly was something important there and you've destabilized your program now.

> and useStruct uses content of pStruct as pointer to struct.

Yes, it uses content of pStruct as pointer to struct - but as I said it now contains the struct itself, not just a pointer.

You must treat the pointer as a distinct type than what it points at. Eg my  finger is a pointer and I am pointing it at a Statue Of Liberty. What you did is you copied the content of Statue Of Liberty into a finger. It won't fit. What you need is to get another Statue-sized memory place, copy the original Statue there and then you can take a finger and point it into new Statue.

Comment: Thanks to all for verifying my thoughts..It's not my code, I don't think it works either :-)