# Error: incompatible types when assigning to and returning to type

Tags: c, linux, pointers, structure

I made a program to update some type structure but on compiling two errors occurred, my program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a {
    char *name;
    int id;
    char *department;
    int num;
};

typedef struct a ab;

void swap(ab *,ab *);
ab * update(ab *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    ab array[2]={{"Saud",137,"Electronics",500},{"Ebad",111,"Telecom",570}};
    ab *q;

    *q=update(&array[0]);
}

ab * update(ab *p)
{
    p->name="Talha";
    p->id=234;
    p->department="Civil";
    p->num=567;

    return *p;
}
```

On compiling, two errors appeared in assigning and returning to pointer. Kindly notify my mistake, and make a correction to it. The errors are,

```
newproject.c: In function ‘main’:

newproject.c:29:4: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘ab   {aka 
 struct a}’ from type ‘ab * {aka struct a *}’

*q=update(&array[0]);

  ^

newproject.c: In function ‘update’:

newproject.c:56:9: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘ab {aka 
struct a}’ but ‘ab * {aka struct a *}’ was expected

return *p;

       ^
```

Comment: You should be able to work it out if you just work out the types on the LHS and RHS. For `*q=update(&array[0]);`: `update` is defined to returns `ab *` but `*q` is of type `ab`. Not to mention that `q` is unintialised and dereferencing it results in an invalid memory access.

Comment: Note that `q` is not initialized to point anywhere reliable before it is dereferenced. That is not a recipe for happiness.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the * in `return *p;`. You want to return a pointer address, not the pointed-at data. This is the reason for the compiler error.
- Please note that `ab *q; *q=update(&array[0]);` also does not work because `q` does not point at valid data. This code is going to cause a program crash or similar.

  See this: [Mysterious crash or “segmentation fault” when data is copied/scanned to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/mysterious-crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-to-an-unini).