# Bus error using char arrays in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, char

I am trying to teach myself C language. My transition from C has been rough so far. I am doing a problem from the Book "Intro to C language" and there is a problem that should read a line from the user and then ask the user for an int. My job was to **find that particular word corresponding to the int**.

**Example**

> Hello World, How are you all doing. // This is the line being read
>
> 2 // the word to be printed to the console

**Expected Output**

> World

Below is a snippet of my code that i think is giving me the bus error.

```
void corrspndToInt (char *theLine, int word, char *result ) {

    int start;
    int end;
    int spaces = 1;
    result = "";

    //int i;

    //search for the nth non-blank character

    for(start = 0; start < strlen(theLine) && (spaces < word); start++ ) {

        if( isspace ( theLine[ start ] ) ) {

            spaces++;
        } // end if

    } // end for loop

    //only need to continue if we haven't gone past the end of the string

    if( start < strlen(theLine) ) {

        //the next blank character is the end

        for ( end = start; end < strlen(theLine) && ( !isspace ( theLine[ end ] ) ) ; end++ ) {

        ;

        } // end for loop

        //we now have the word

        result = strncpy ( result, theLine+start, end - start); 

     } // end if

}
```

This is how i am printing the result in `main` function.

```
printf("%s\n", result );
```

Now that i have been teaching C language to myself and through SO i learned that returning char arrays should not be done. There were two methods dynamic allocation using function `malloc` and there was another method which is the one i implemented in my code. I have checked my other method and there seems to be nothing wrong with that. The problem here is with this method as it is not getting the correct word.

I have been trying to debug my program but apparently Mac doesn't accept the `gdb` command. I have installed the command line tools and everything else but it still says

> Command not found

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction here? I have been overthinking this problem from the last 1 hour now.

Comment: It would be easier to get help if you post a [mcve].

Comment: `result = "";` : I think this is  bad idea.

Comment: Should i use a for loop to manually assign every index a space? Also what could be the reason for bus error. I have checked my other method and it is working fine. The problem seems to be with this one. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: In this case, such initialization is not necessary. `result = "";` change the address pointed to by the pointer. This same such as `corrspndToInt (line, 2, "")`.

Comment: So you mean that they are the same. Okay. i'll change that. I get the idea that every time we call a char array we are technically calling it like this `&array[0]` so by your logic, the first element will be space. Correct me if i am wrong with my basics? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: If you know the length and location of a word, do the following. `strncpy(result, position_of_top_of_word/* theLine+start */, length_of_word/* end - start */); result[length_of_word] = '\0';`

Comment: Also see [Mysterious crash or “segmentation fault” when data is copied/scanned to an uninitialized pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/mysterious-crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-to-an-unini).

Answer (score 0):

First, you must allocate enough space for `result` to hold the word, meaning

```
result = malloc (sizeof(char) * (length_of_the_word+1));
```

given that you have found out the length of the word you want to copy. One extra because we want to append terminating `\0` character at the end of the string when you use `strncpy`

From the function it is unclear that you have allocated space for result or not. I hope this should help you complete the task.

Comment: I have allocated space in my `main` method. I don't want to use `malloc` function that is the reason i implemented the above way of returning a char array.