# C seg fault double pointer assignment inside struct and not outside it.

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

So this is a simple assignment that works pretty well:

```
int **a = malloc(sizeof(int*));
int *b;
a[0] = b;
```

But when I try to do the same inside a struct via a pointer to struct:

```
typedef struct jojo
{
  int **a ;
}jojo;
```

Lets say I allocate for a pointer to jojo called alpha a lot of space like for 100 integers...

```
jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
int *b;
alpha->a[0] = b;
```

Here there is a segmentation fault.
I am completely lost, so I am asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: One problem: `malloc(sizeof(int)*100)` -> `malloc(sizeof(jojo)*100)`

Comment: `alpha` is initialized, but `a` field isn't initialized, even less allocated

Comment: So [how many questions using invalid pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-to-an-uninitialized-po) do we need per hour?

Comment: @MichaelWalz `malloc(sizeof(jojo)*100)` -> `malloc(sizeof(*alpha)*100)`

Comment: In any case, this sounds like an XY problem: **who needs pointers to pointers to integers in an array**? You say yourself: "space for 100 integers" but you actually don't have integers there, but pointers to integer objects... could you enlighten us about the actual use case, the actual [X in your problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `alpha` points to a `jojo`, but `jojo` has inside of it a pointer to `int` pointer (`**a`) which you didn't initialize but ar etrying to access.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala since the space for integers is not qualittively diferent from the space for any other type, I used it just for getting a massive amount of space to experiment. Obviously the example I put is an instance of my real problem in wich I deal with more complex data, but since here is the root of the trouble itś fine like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

you only allocate memory for *the structure* (and much more than is needed for the structure) and not somewhere for the members inside to point. What's worse is that `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, its contents will be *indeterminate*.

That last part means the pointer `a` will be seemingly random and dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve your problem you need to allocate memory for the structure first, *then* allocate memory for the pointer inside the structure:

```
jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof *alpha);  // Allocate memory for the structure
alpha->a = malloc(100 * sizeof *alpha->a);  // Allocate memory for a 100 pointers to `int`
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not pointing anywhere. You only reserved memory for structure. You have to reserve memory for `a` too.

```
int *b;

//Reserve memory for 100 structures
jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(*alpha)*100);

//Reserve memory for a pointer on first structure
alpha->a = malloc(sizeof(*alpha->a)*1);
alpha->a[0] = b;
```

Let me just tell you that if `b` has no value, it is *undefined behavior* if you dereference it.

Also, please check how I used arguments in `sizeof` keyword for detecting size of memory to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
  jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

is *bad*, because, `alpha` is not related to `sizeof (int) * 100` and once it changes, you'll be in trouble. In case you meant (or, actually you want) to write

```
 jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(jojo)*100);
```

or better,

```
 jojo *alpha = malloc(sizeof(*alpha)*100);  // no dependency on hard-coded type
```

That said, you have allocated memory only for `alpha`, not for it's members!

You also need to make the member `a` to ***point to some valid memory location*** before you can dereference it.