# C function to read binary file doesn't work if used by other function.?

Tags: c, fread, stdio, unsigned-char

I wrote this function to return an `unsigned char *` containing the data from any file(using `rb`read mode) it looks like this:

```
uchar * get_file_data (char *f_name, luint *len) {

    // verify file
    struct stat sBuffer;
    int iRc;

    iRc = stat(f_name, &sBuffer);
    if (iRc != 0) {
        printf("Failed to get file size\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    // read file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(f_name, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    uchar *buff = (uchar *) malloc(sBuffer.st_size);
    *len = fread(buff, 1, sBuffer.st_size, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return buff;

}
```

Types:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned long int luint;
```

Now this works when run from the `int main()` function like so:

```
luint *len;
uchar *dat = get_file_data(argv[2] /* argument congaing filename */, len);
print_uchar(dat, len);
free(dat);
```

However when calling `has_checksum(argv[2]);` from `int main()` i get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` though the use is seemingly the same.

```
int has_checksum (char *f_name) {

    luint *p_len;
    uchar *p_f_data = get_file_data(f_name, p_len); /* this fails */

    /* more code, never reached */

}
```

When i try running my program with the following `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // verifying other arguments (not filename) */

    luint *len;
    uchar *dat = get_file_data(argv[2], len);
    print_uchar(dat, len);
    free(dat);

    has_checksum(argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
$ ./md5 -add ../<filename> 
<file contents (correct)>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tested if `char *f_name` in `get_file_data()` was the same each time(using `printf("%s\n", f_name);` immediately when entering `get_file_data()`), and it was.

---

**System:**
-- VM Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit) -- VirtualBox

Comment: You're supposed declare `luint len;` and pass in `&len` - now you have an uninitialized pointer pointing to who knows where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer in both cases, but you're getting "lucky" in `main()` and it appears to work. You need to pass the address of an actual integer:

```
luint len;
uchar *dat = get_file_data(argv[2], &len);
```

You see, when you declare `luint *len;`, you've declared a pointer but nothing for it to point at. It contains an uninitialized value and may point anywhere. You may or may not be able to write to that location.

Comment: Seems that should be it. 3 people looking to find it and u do in 3 min or less. Will try this. Also thanks to @Antti Haapala