# char* in struct is re-writable, but in main() function is not. why?

Tags: c, string, pointers, literals

I wonder the difference of same char* between when it resides **in struct** and **in main() function**.

Here is the code:

```
struct student {
    char* name;
};

int main() {

    // char* in struct
    struct student bob;
    bob.name = "alice";
    bob.name = "bob";
    printf("name: %s\n", bob.name);

    // char* in main()
    char *name = "kim";
    *name = "lee";
    printf("name: %s\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
name: bob
name: kim
```

In the case of using **struct**, the value of student bob.name was changed from "alice" to "bob". However, in the latter case, the value of char* name wasn't changed.

I think that the reason why "kim" didn't changed to "lee" is char *name was pointing literal "kim".

If I'm right, why bob.name was changed from "alice" to "bob"? It shoudn't have changed to "bob" because "alice" was also literal.

What's the difference?

Comment: one is `name = ...` the other is `*name = ...`?

Comment: `*name = "lee";` should not even compile, or you should get at least a warning.

Comment: Try `* bob.name = "bob"` to be the same as `* name =`. And always try to have 0 warnings!

Comment: @MichaelWalz unfortunately it does compile. Unless you have warnings enabled and treat warnings as errors. This is `C`

Comment: @MichaelWalz I also guessed Visual Studio would show complie error, but it compiled successfully.(i think that line was ignored)

Comment: The compiler doesn't just ignore lines; and VS2017 will show a warning if you use at least /W1

Comment: @bolov The compiler is _required_ to give a diagnostic message for this, by the C standard. If it does so in the form of a warning or error is up to the compiler. And if the programmer chose to ignore the warning, it is then the programmer's problem that the code doesn't work.

Comment: @stjin Yeah, There are 1 warning as you said. It was just warning, not compile error as bolov mentioned above.

Comment: Apart from the C syntax violation - the code is not valid C, see [What is the difference between char s and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s) and [Crash or “segmentation fault” when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ).

Comment: A warning is not "just a warning". While the compiler doesn't immediately stop compiling at this point, it is still some issue that needs to be looked into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code invokes *Undefined Behavior*,

since you do:

```
struct student { char* name;};
struct student bob;
bob.name = "alice";
```

i.e. you are making the pointer `name`, point to a string literal.

Then you just:

```
bob.name = "bob";
```

make the pointer point to another string literal, which is OK, since you just modify where the pointer points to, not the string literal that it points to (for example `bob.name[3] = 'f';`, which would lead in a Segmentation Fault, since it would attempt to modify a string literal - forbidden).

If you plan to make your pointer point to string literals, then I suggest you declare it that way:

```
const char* name;
```

which allows you to change where the pointer points to, but not the contents of the string literal the pointers points to.

---

Now this:

```
char *name = "kim";
```

is a **string literal**, where its contents cannot be modified. And when you do:

```
*name = "lee";
```

you just do something that it's not allowed, resulting an ill-formed program.

Comment: 1st case: he doesn't need memory allocation. He just points the pointer to a string literal. That is OK. The only thing that is dangerous is having `char*` instead of `const char*` to point to a string literal, but since he doesn't modify it's contents he gets lucky: it's OK. No UB as far as I can recall the rules for `C`

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not compile.

*name = "lee"; // Error 1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [4]' to 'char'

The reason is that *name points to a char and "lee" is a char[4].