# Program crashes in the `scanf` function. Why?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char key, vector;
    char plainText[101];
    char cipher;
    int i, cipherValue;
    int keyLength, IVLength;

    scanf("%s", key);
    scanf("%s", vector);

    return 0;
}
```

My program crashes after I input values for the `scanf` parts. I don't understand why.

Comment: Compiler warnings: enable them (here, `-Wformat` for `gcc` or `clang`) and heed them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ) - it's not an exact duplicate, but the reason is similar and reading the solution should be enough.

Comment: @viraptor: These aren’t even pointers!

Comment: @DavisHerring I understand - and that's why I'm saying it's not an exact duplicate. The answers there are better than anything we could write here though. (unless you want to explain pointer / value difference from scratch :) )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean for me to do @DavisHerring

Comment: @Occazn: The compiler can help you find (many of) these basic mistakes without having to ask here.  You do have to know how to turn the warnings on, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
scanf("%s", key);
scanf("%s", vector);
```

is:

1. `key` and `vector` are of type `char`, not pointers to `char`. The can hold one character only.<sup>1</sup>
2. With `%s` `scanf` expects a pointer to `char`. As it stands right now, you
   are passing uninitialized integer values as if it were pointers, that's
   undefined behaviour and your program crashes as a result of it. The compiler
   must have given you a warning about this, don't ignore the compiler's warnings,
   they are there to help you, not annoy you.

The correct version:

```
char key[101], vector[101];
...
scanf("%s", key);
scanf("%s", vector);

// or to limit the number of bytes
// written in the buffer, as pointed out
// in the comments by user viraptor
scanf("%100s", key);
scanf("%100s", vector);
```

For more information about `scanf`, please read [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

---

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup>A string in C is a sequence of characters that ends with the
`'\0'`-terminating byte. A string with one single character needs a `char` array
of dimension 2 or more. In general, a `char` array of dimension `n` can store
strings with maximal length of `n-1`. You have to keep that in mind when passing
pointers to `char` to functions when they expect strings. A pointer to a single
`char` will lead to undefined behaviour because it overflows.

Comment: `%100s` is probably more correct here :)

Comment: @viraptor yes, that's right, I added that in the answer.