# Learning C: Passing strings between functions

Tags: c

I am having difficulty passing strings between functions in C. Here is the most simplified parts of my code that contain the errors: First, the function prototype for transpose, which performs a certain unary operation on strings. I've heard we declare strings with char *str, so this is correct?

```
char *transpose(*char);
//[Error] expected primary-expression before 'char'
```

Here is the use of the transpose function in main(). I indicated which lines produce errors with the following comment.

```
int main() {

    char *input;
    scanf("%s",&input);

    char *result;
    result = transpose(input);
    //[Error] 'transpose' cannot be used as a function

    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
```

Finally is the function definition for transpose:

```
char *transpose(char *text) {
    char *T = text;
    return T;
}
```

Comment: `char *T = text;` goes out of scope as soon as you return from that function, I believe.

Comment: @DavidVereb it does, but its pointee doesn't.

Comment: `char *str` is a _pointer_. Where does it point to?

Comment: The code as posted doesn't generate the error messages you mentioned.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Quentin ah yes, whoops.  Now when I compile this code myself it compiles just fine when removing the & in front of input in the `scanf()` function, so I'm not sure where OP is having an issue.

Comment: `input` does not point to any buffer, anyways.

Comment: "*heard we declare strings with char *str, so this is correct*" unfortunately not.  `char *` just defines a pointer. No `char`-array here, which is the least you need to have string.

Comment: `char *input;` -> `char input[100];`. And `scanf("%s",&input);` -> `scanf("%s", input);` Read the chapters dealing with sitring and with pointers in your C text book.

Comment: The question is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/37549594/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Comment: Ok I updated the new errors. I'm receiving many different answers for this problem, all I'm trying to do is create an identify function for strings.

Comment: If you are just learning C, I strongly suggest that you avoid using `scanf`.   It will cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: When you function definition is starting with `char *transpose(char *text)`, that is taking a pointer to `char`, a `char*`, then why you make the prototype to be `char *transpose(*char)`? What to you expected `*char` to be, this poor lonely cripple? ;)

Comment: The function prototype should be a copy of the function definition, with a semicolon added on the end. So `char *transpose(char *text);` is the prototype that should be in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your codes, firstly here

```
char *input; /* pointer variable should be initialized with valid memory */
scanf("%s",&input); /* this causes compiler warning, but seems you ignored ? */
```

`input` doesn't have valid memory & scanning a uninitialized pointer may cause crash. So either you can create `input` as char array like

```
char input[20]; 
scanf("%s",input); /* & is not required as input name itself address */
```

Or allocate memory dynamically for `input` like below

```
char *input = malloc(SIZE); /* define the SIZE value */
scanf("%s",input);
```

Sample Code

```
char *transpose(char *text) {
    char *T = text;
    return T;
}
int main(void) {
        char input[20];/* size of array you can define it, I just took 20 char */
        scanf("%s",input);
        char *result = transpose(input);
        printf("%s",result);
        return 0;
}
```

As others suggested in comments its better to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. For e.g

```
char input[20];
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0; /* to remove the trailing \n if copied, use strcspn() */
```