# Why does printing a character with %s gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why does printing a character with %s gives a segmentation fault everytime?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c = 'a';
  printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

if may be it's due to not getting '\0' and it continues to read unless accessing read only memory locations, why does this happens all the time? (as it should get \0 somewhere (most probably) as this code does

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c[2];
  c[0] = 'a';
  c[1] = 'a'; //skipping '\0'
  printf("%s",c); //aa..(then some random output)
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry If the question was silly, I am just a beginner.

Comment: you got it .. using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior. It doesn't seg fault "every time" for all conditions on all systems. Just so happens the conditions are right on your system right now that it's segfaulting. Use `"%c"` to print a character. `"%s"` tells `printf` to keep printing until it encounters the terminator, it appears that's not happening before it touches some memory it's not allowed to touch. If you change the compiler flags, use a different compiler, try tomorrow, try running on your buddy's machine, it may not segfault.

Comment: In the first code, you have `char c = 'a';
  printf("%s",c);` — this tries to print the string starting at an address that is represented by the value in `c` and some other bytes.  That isn't a valid address, and on your machine triggers a crash.  You would need `printf("%s", &c);` to pass a valid address, but that would lead to problems with sundry other characters being printed because the chances are there wouldn't be a null `'\0'` after the `a`.  That's more or less what's going on in your second fragment.

Comment: @yano: even worse, it is not actually printing the character, but interpreting the character as a pointer to see what to print. It is extremely likely that pointer is pointing to memory region that is off limits, thus segv. It doesn't even come to looking for a zero.

Comment: read compiler warnings and it'll tell you the problem immediately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ) replace "uninitialize" by "invalid" the answer is the same

Comment: `%s` is for strings only, `char`s have to be `printf()`d with `%c`.

Comment: @Amadan Ah yes, absolutely correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does printing a character with %s gives a segmentation fault everytime?

Because `%s` tells `printf` that the argument is a *pointer* to a string, and because most modern systems protect low-address memory from all accesses (to prevent bugs like this from staying undetected).

When you pass `'a'`, to `printf`, it gets a value `0x41` (`ASCII` code for `a`), *interprets* that value as a pointer, which points into the lowest page of memory, which is protected with no-access -> `SIGSEGV`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of %s printf is expecting a pointer to a string .
So while printing printf tries to print from address the c(value of c) stores which could be invalid(Because it's not actually an address), hence resulting in segfault.

You could do printf("%s", &c); // this could produce some Garbage values

Answer (score 0):

This is what you intend to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 'a';
    printf("%c",c);  /* <<<< use %c instead of %s, read printf(3) */
    return 0;
}
```

If you do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[2];
    c[0] = 'a';
    c[1] = 'a'; //skipping '\0'
    printf("%s",c); //aa..(then some random output)
    return 0;
}
```

this time you are passing `printf()` a pointer (the array name `c` alone is interpreted as the address to the first element, so it can be passed to `printf()` with the `%s` format specifier.  This time, the lack of a `\0` makes `printf()` to continue printing until it gets a `\0`, you can change your code into:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[2];
    c[0] = 'a';
    c[1] = '\0';
    printf("%s",c); // you get only a
    return 0;
}
```

and you'll get `a` as printed output.