# How to concatenate char* strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to generate a `name` string by concatenating random vowels and consonants.

I've tried using `strcat` to concatenate random vowels/consonants to the `name` string, but that results in segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

[...]

```
char randomVowel() {
    char * vowels = "aeiou";
    return vowels[randomRange(0, 4)];
}

char randomConsonant() {
    char * consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxwyz";
    return consonants[randomRange(0, 20)];
}


char * randomName() { 
    int i; 
    char * name;

    for (i = 0; i < randomNumber(20); i++){
        i % 2 ? strcat(name, randomVowel()) : strcat(name, randomConsonant());
    }

    return name;
}

int main () {

    printf("%s\n", randomName());

    return 0;
}
```

What is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: `char * name;` is an uninitialized pointer. Passing that as the first parameter of `strcat` invokes *undefined behavior*. The documentation clearly states it needs to be a null-terminated byte string: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

Comment: also... `strcat` wants two strings, i.e. `char *`, but your functions `randomVowel` and `randomConsonant` both return `char` values.

Comment: See this question in the C FAQ concerning [uninitialized pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)

Comment: also... even if you initialized `name` inside of `randomName` you can't return a pointer to local variable.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to do something like this:

```
void appendChar(char *name, int len, char c) {
    name[len] = c;
}

char * randomName(char *name) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < randomNumber(20); i++){
        i % 2 ? appendChar(name, i, randomVowel()) : appendChar(name, i, randomConsonant());
    }

    return name;
}

int main () {
    char name[32] = "";
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    printf("%s\n", randomName(name));

    return 0;
}
```

This way you are just putting each character your generate at the end of your `name` string.  You usually want to seed your random number generator in your `main` function, so I put that there for you too.