# Passing by reference when I want to pass by value?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, pthreads, png

When I print out my `order[]` array (or even the value of the previous index `order[num-1])`, every index is filled with the same value. Is this because when I `pthread_join`, I am changing `all_png` by reference and therefore when I set `order[num] = all_png[0]`, when the value of `all_png` changes, so does every value of order[] which I had previously stored?

```
pthread_t *p_tids = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * 1);      
char *all_pngs[1] = {0};
int num;
char *order[50] = {0};
while(array_is_full(order) == 0){
//use thread to call CURL
          pthread_create(p_tids, NULL, get_png, NULL);
          pthread_join(p_tids[0], (void **)&(all_pngs[0]));
          //parse the png name and put it in the correct order
          sscanf(all_pngs[0], "%*[^0-9]%d", &num);
          if(order[num] == NULL){
          order[num] = all_pngs[0];
          printf("%s %s\n", order[num-1], order[num]);
 }
```

Also, `array_is_full` also works as supposed to and just checks if the array is still filled with 0's or not. If there are still 0's (not full yet) return 0.

The `get_png` method simply returns a void pointer to a char*. And `fname` is simply a `char[]` that holds the png file name (i.e. output_3.png). This function works as it's supposed to.

```
char *a = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
a = fname;
return ((void *)a);
```

The output looks something like this.

```
(null) ./output_19.png
(null) ./output_16.png
(null) ./output_24.png
(null) ./output_21.png
(null) ./output_38.png
(null) ./output_5.png
(null) ./output_8.png
(null) ./output_7.png
(null) ./output_46.png
(null) ./output_43.png
(null) ./output_35.png
(null) ./output_11.png
(null) ./output_4.png
(null) ./output_48.png
./output_6.png ./output_6.png
./output_44.png ./output_44.png
./output_22.png ./output_22.png
./output_49.png ./output_49.png
(null) ./output_28.png
./output_47.png ./output_47.png
(null) ./output_26.png
(null) ./output_33.png
./output_17.png ./output_17.png
./output_18.png ./output_18.png
(null) ./output_32.png
(null) ./output_14.png
./output_45.png ./output_45.png
(null) ./output_42.png
./output_27.png ./output_27.png
./output_39.png ./output_39.png
(null) ./output_31.png
(null) ./output_30.png
./output_9.png ./output_9.png
```

As you can see the previous index of order is being updated to the current value of the current index even though I thought I was only setting `order[num]` not `order[num-1]` (which should have been set previously).

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this?

Let me know if anything is unclear or if more code is needed. I am quite new to posting on here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There re some parts of code missing from your post for a fuller answer but, if you are trying to pass a whole array by value (i.e. *copy* all elements to the function) then you'll have to either make an explicit copy in the caller, or make the array a member (the only member) of a `struct` and pass that.

Comment: What parts should I include to make it more understandable?

Comment: You should post code approaching something we can compile and test.

Comment: In particular, you should present a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  But this is not necessarily a question of "what parts".  An appropriate MRE is sometimes derived from your original code, but usually not by just clipping out selected parts.  Follow the link for more information.

Comment: Anyway, my crystal ball tells me `get_png()` always returns *the same* pointer, so that assigning all those return values to various elements of `order` leaves them pointing to the same memory location, which will reflect the data most recently written there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Could you elaborate on that idea? I'm not quite sure what you mean though I think you may be right. How can I make it so that assigning various elements of order not point to the same memory location? Can I somehow, instead of pointing just, set the value equal to the return value from get_png(). Also, thanks I will look into MRE.

Comment: @SteamedBun, it starts with presenting an MRE in the question.  I'm not prepared to comment any further on code that I do not see.  Note also that crafting a *bona fide* MRE is a useful debugging exercise in its own right.

Comment: Also, `char *a = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);` followed by `a = fname;` is a definite code-smell. If you think that copies the string from `fname` to `a` then you're wrong - it replaces the pointer to the newly allocated memory, which can then no longer be accessed or freed. Use `strcpy` to copy the data.

Comment: @AdrianMole that completely solved the issue. Thanks so much! Could you possibly explain that last part of why it is wrong (for future reference). Trying to understand this, a is just a pointer to fname which gets deallocated after the method finishes? Or something like that? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: There are lots of posts on Stack Overflow explaining the difference between copying a `char*` pointer and copying the data that is pointed-to. [Here's one I made earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729550/10871073).