# Comparing two ways of initializing an int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

Suppose I have a pointer

```
int *x;
```

Then I need to let the pointer point to an int of value, say 42.

Should I do this:

```
   *x = 42;
```

or this:

```
  int y = 42;
  x = &y;
```

? What is the usual practice?

Comment: I assume you are doing `*x=42` after a call to `x = malloc`, aren't you?

Comment: I was thinking that because as long as x is non-null, *x=42 should work even without malloc. Right? It would be like we just put 42 to a random memory case, but what would be wrong with it?

Comment: but random memory cannot guarantee it will be successfully stored, that would be **UB** (undefined behavior)

Comment: Regarding the common misconception that you can somehow store data inside pointers, see [Crash or “segmentation fault” when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this declaration

```
int *x;
```

the pointer `x` either is equal to `NULL` (if it is declared outside any function) or has an indeterminate value. So dereferencing the pointer like

```
*x = 42;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You can write either

```
int y = 42;
x = &y;
```

or

```
x = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
*x = 42;
```

Comment: Suppose x is a local variable.  Does "int *x; *x = 42;" is still undefined behavior?  I was thinking that because x is guaranteed to be non-null, this one should work even without malloc, no?

Comment: @zell The pointer is uninitialized and has indeterminate value. So you may not dereference it.

Comment: @zell: After `int *x;`, `x` is not guaranteed to be non-null. What made you think it was guaranteed to be non-null?

Comment: Check the return value of `malloc()` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```c
int *x = 42;
```

you assigne the pointeur `x` to the memory case `42`, that gonna make a segmentation fault.
The right way to do what you wan't is:

```c
int y = 42;
x = &y;
```

Comment: `int *x = 42;` isn't valid C and the OP isn't doing that either, so why did you bring that case up?

Comment: It does not necessary cause a segmentation fault, many platforms do not even have the concept of segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

x gets the adress of y (&y)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int y=42;
      int x=&y;
      printf("\nY = %d is at adress X = %d \n",y,x);
}
```

Comment: Your code causes UB. `"%d"` expects a `int`, not a `int *` variable.