# C Array in Struct - Segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, struct, segment

I am trying to get a better knowledge of C and I am currently writing and experimenting with different code snippets.
The actual one is making me crazy because I have no idea what I need to change so it will work.

I want to store something into a struct as a char array, but when I want to read the stored char array, I always get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct connector {
    char *subject;
};

int main() {
    char *subject = NULL;
    struct connector *conn;
    subject = "TEE";
    printf("%s\n", subject);
    
    conn->subject = subject;
    
    printf("%s\n", conn->subject);
    
    return 0;
}
```

So why the second printf is having this problem ?

Comment: The variable `conn`  is a pointer, but *where does it point?*

Comment: you did not allocated memory for the conn

Comment: See: [Crash or “segmentation fault” when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a struct pointer `struct connector *conn` which was not initialized.

You may declare it on the stack `struct connector conn;` or allocate a memory for it with `malloc` as follows: `struct connector *conn = (struct connector *)malloc(sizeof(struct connector));`.