# gethostbyname Unknown Host

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to get the `IP` address from an `URL` but `gethostbyname` always says `Unknown host`. Hope someone can point out my fault.
Here is my code

```
char *handleAddress(char *URL)
{
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i;
    char *ip = NULL;
    printf("Search IP for this = %s\n", URL);
    if ((he = gethostbyname(URL)) == NULL) // get the host info
    {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        ip = "No Such DNS";
        return ip;
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **)he->h_addr_list;

    for (i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) //Return the first one;
    {
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
        return ip;
    }
}
```

Expected: URL: `www.google.com` return IP: `173.194.72.106`

Comment: Calling host name as `URL` looks weird. What are you passing for that? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also your code has this problem (not duplicate): [c - Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)

Comment: If `URL` is really a URL, then this won't work.  You need to pass a host name, not a URL.  E.g., you need to pass `amazon.com`, not `http://amazon.com`.

Comment: Have you read the man page? *"The `gethostbyname*()`, `gethostbyaddr*()`, `herror()`, and `hstrerror()` functions are obsolete.  Applications should use `getaddrinfo(3)`, `getnameinfo(3)`, and `gai_strerror(3)` instead."* You may want to work through [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for handling the transition.

Comment: @CKJ - What does `nslookup www.google.com` say?

Answer (score 0):

It was an idiotic problem. First, the `URL` should not have `\n` in the end. Second, I changed the loop to

```
char **he_ptr;
he_ptr = he->h_addr_list;
for (; *he_ptr != NULL; he_ptr++)
{
    return inet_ntop(he->h_addrtype, *he_ptr, buff, sizeof(buff));
}
```

Then, somehow it worked. I did not figure out why it worked by changing a way to iterate it.