# Assigning 16 bit pointer reference to 16 bit value results in LoadStoreError

Tags: c, memory-management, runtime-error, allocation, esp32

I have the following function:

```cpp
static void ClearDisplay(void)
{
  int X,Y;
  GuiConst_INT16U *PixelPtr;
  GuiConst_INT16U PIXEL_OFF = 65535; 

  PixelPtr = (GuiConst_INT16U*)sgl.CurLayerBufPtr;
  for (Y = 0; Y < (GuiConst_INT16S)sgl.CurLayerHeight; Y++)
    for (X = 0; X < (GuiConst_INT16S)sgl.CurLayerWidth; X++)
    {
      *PixelPtr = PIXEL_OFF;
      PixelPtr++;
    }
}
```

The following line causes a SIGTRAP interrupt when debugging, throwing a Guru Meditation Error with code `LoadStoreError`:

```cpp
*PixelPtr = PIXEL_OFF;
```

After searching this up, I found the [following](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/fatal-errors.html):

**This exception may happen in the following cases:**

- If the application has attempted to do an 8- or 16- bit read to, or write from, a memory region which only supports 32-bit reads/writes. For example, dereferencing a char* pointer to instruction memory (IRAM, IROM) will result in such an error.
- If the application has attempted to write to a read-only memory region, such as IROM or DROM.

So I'm assuming the problem relates to the former since neither `PixelPtr` nor `PIXEL_OFF` are assigned `const`. I thought the problem would be cleared up if I set them both to the same datatype, `GuiConst_INT16U` (which is an `unsigned short` in the code), but the problem persists. What am I missing here?

Comment: What address does `PixelPtr` point to?

Comment: You're using a variable called `sgl` but we have no idea what it is or where it came from. Please provide all the relevant code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)